# Can a combination of purple-green or pink-green make a design look bad?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-theory, illustration, color-profile

Just like we use some green on red (not all cases, depends on saturation and lightness) as shown in last image, which looks not very common & attractive when it comes to illustrations for social media, is there anything such problem with this design?

I designed this for Mother's Day. Now, the design looks okay to me. There's MOM written on flower, and the Mother and Child part on the right.

I tried purple and green, pink and green, but something, especially the colors look bad to me. Either the combination of green and pink is not working or something else, I'm not sure.

**Is there some blunder here in terms of color?**

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: The colors look fine to me but I didn't notice the mom or Mom with child until you mentioned it because they're very subtle

Comment: Subtle means? Small and less visible?

Comment: Would have been better if downvoter had explained how I can explain this question better.

Comment: I down voted. The *opinions* about the *specific* use of color in a *specific* piece of art are not only *completely* opinion based, but also *completely* unhelpful to any future visitor. It is just a bad question from my perspective. -- However, I don't find the coloring bad in either of your samples... but again.. that's my *opinion*. My down votes are *not* personal, they are *entirely* based upon either the effort put into a question or how helpful the question would be to *anyone* else. No one else will benefit from the opinionated answers here.

Comment: How would you choose a "correct" answer here??? You could *only* choose an *opinion* which aligns with your *opinion*. So **all** answers are complete guesses, or random shots to come to an opinion you like. Nothing is based in fact.

Comment: Updated it by the way.

Comment: I think your update is even worse.  Who says using green on red looks ugly?  I think your question is based more on your own personal likes/dislikes.

Comment: @BillyKerr my mistake. I didn't explain it better. I've updated it again.

Comment: I genuinely wanted to know the problem (if there were any). If you think so I can delete this question. I'll try to ask better questions. I don't want downvotes :(

Comment: I don't think you should delete it since you already have some answers. I've removed my downvote now, since I see you at least have made an effort to fix it.  Just be aware that question about choice of colour can be very subjective, and subjective questions tend to generate opinions rather than facts.

Comment: Vikas, I still feel this is asking for an *opinion* on a specific piece of artwork. For an example of a more widely useful question regarding specific color combinations  [**see here**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17446/is-there-a-good-way-to-establish-a-green-yellow-red-colour-scheme)

Comment: I read it. Got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of colors is very subjective, and therefore little information can be added. In particular, the colors chosen are very architectural, although speaking of color perception, pages can be filled.

---

The problem in the illustration is not the color choice but the **contrast** and **color areas proportions**.

By decomposing the image colors, there are three hues and five tonal values:
[image: Colors 1]

It's easier to see it in grayscale:

[image: B&W]

A dominant color for each example, a subordinate and an accent:

[image: colors 3]

After a little analysis there are some aspects to highlight:

- The most relevant color after the flowers is the leaves green, where,
  according to the explanation of the question, the eye should not
  stop, and is where it's headed first. The green leaves ***eat*** the
  whole illustration.
- The illustration is playing with a complementary combination: magenta and red-pink are complementary colors of green and blue-green. A combination of complementary colors is normally used to attract attention due to the optical effect that it produces in the vision. Any secondary or second reading element will go completely unnoticed.

[image]

- My proposal would be, keeping the same colors, modify the **contrast** and change the **color areas proportions**:

  - Raise the secondary elements (the leaves) tonal value (make them lighter)
  - Increase the area occupied by the second reading elements, as they timidly appear in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/124528/120647)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any book where I can read about these 3 types of colors?

Comment: I have none in mind, any color theory book. [This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/113194/120647) can help.

Answer (score 3):

Subjective opinion: No problem with colors, but recolor MOM to make it visible. It can have the background color, even a little lighter, add grained glows to blend it:

[image]

The screenshot can be too detoriated. Check it here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7eq9tmxxp1l6hb/MOM.psd?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Actually writing MOM on flower was little bad design (would need a lot more effort to fix it). I realized this after reading few comments here.

And the problem which I saw was little more saturation in purple color, grains, pink grains. So here's how I fixed it. It looks better to me now:

[image]